# Groupby pandas calculate percentage

Tags: pandas

I have a groupby object as follows after i ran:

```
grouped_mask=L2014_2.groupby(['state'])
grouped_mask.mask.value_counts()

state  mask 
AL     False    105931
       True         77
AR     False     67788
       True       1774
AZ     False     90068
       True        151
CA     False    586184
       True          4
CO     False     75188
       True      14360
CT     False     78270
       True          1
```

Now i need to calculate what is percentage of true in each state. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: does `grouped_mask.mask.value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())` work?

Comment: Not really seem right, as it gives me this 
state  mask 
    AL     False   1.00
           True    0.00
    AR     False   0.97
             True    0.03
    AZ     False   1.00
             True    0.00
    CA     False   1.00
              True    0.00
    CO     False   0.84
              True    0.16
    CT     False   1.00
              True    0.00

Comment: That looks like a display trimming the significant digits if you multiply by 100 do you see more digits?

Comment: It works Thank a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can set the `normalize` parameter to obtain the relative frequencies:

```
grouped_mask.mask.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

just multiply by 100 to get the percentages :-)

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` on the first level and then apply a lambda that divides the True/False counts against the sum:

```
In [20]:
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum() * 100)

Out[20]:
                 Count
state mask            
AL    False  99.927364
      True    0.072636
AR    False  97.449757
      True    2.550243
AZ    False  99.832629
      True    0.167371
CA    False  99.999318
      True    0.000682
CO    False  83.963908
      True   16.036092
CT    False  99.998722
      True    0.001278
```

To filter the above to get just the `False` labels you can use advanced indexing using [`slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/advanced.html#using-slicers)s:

```
In [33]:
gp = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum() * 100)
gp.loc(axis=0)[slice(None),False]

Out[33]:
                 Count
state mask            
AL    False  99.927364
AR    False  97.449757
AZ    False  99.832629
CA    False  99.999318
CO    False  83.963908
CT    False  99.998722
```

Comment: Do you know how to take only the True values after this? I do not want the False values

Comment: where `gp` is the result of the above then this works: `
`gp.loc(axis=0)[slice(None),False]` also you can upvote

Comment: There are up and down voting buttons at the top left of my answer are you able to see/click on them?

Comment: ohh, i just clicked the buttons

Comment: Yes you just click on them to register a up/down vote

Comment: When i try to run another groupedby obejct using:
gp.loc(axis=0)[slice(None),False]
It gives me error like : 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'

Comment: Ah you need to sort the index in that case, see this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex

Comment: i sorted using this gp.sort_index(level=0),
It still give me the same erro :
When i try to run another groupedby obejct using: gp.loc(axis=0)[slice(None),False] It gives me error like : 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'

Comment: You have to sort all levels, I can't help unless you post information, probably as a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
gp=grouped_mask.mask.value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100*x/float(x.sum()))   

state  mask 
AL     False    94.37
       True      5.63
AR     False    73.85
       True     26.15
AZ     False    91.88
       True      8.12
CA     False    99.57
       True      0.43
CO     False    64.66
       True     35.34
gp.sort_index(level=0)
gp.loc(axis=0)[slice(None),False]
```

KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'

Comment: I sorted level=1 too. it still gives me the multi index slicing error

Comment: I also sorted try using level="state", still saying KeyError

Comment: Thus should really be a new question not an answer, also you need to assign the result of sort as it's not in place